# A more efficient way to highlight a row in ng-repeat? ... the angular way

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I've illustrated this idea here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/lPHWba9e4WqXmQLMmplv?p=info

Imagine a list of items built with ng-repeat...

```
      <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
           <td id="{{item.id}}">item.id</td>
      </tr>
```

I would like a way for an outside module to highlight one of the rows. One way is to use jquery:

```
     function hilite(id){
        $('#'+id).css('background-color', '#f33');  
     }
```

What is the angular way? ... here's one option:

```
      <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
           <td css="{{hiliteID==item.id && 'background:#f33;'}}" id="{{item.id}}">item.id</td>
      </tr>
```

**But wouldnt this way be much slower?** (Imagine this in an app that is already burdened by angular needing to $watch tens of thousands of items in a $scope... where little things matter)

Check my plunkr... can you think of a better way to do this... that is not jquery?
http://plnkr.co/edit/lPHWba9e4WqXmQLMmplv?p=info

Comment: If your app has "tens of thousands of items" you have a problem. Regarding your question - angularjs is using dirty evaluation so you'r seconds approach is the "angular way" as you put it (for better of worst).

Comment: use the ng-style directive.
You can put expressions inside ng-style.
<td ng-style="{ 'some-css-property': angular expr }">

Comment: @haki - this is for academics sake. my app actually only has a few thousand at the most, but there is a lot of other heavy stuff going on . Im not saying this way will cripple the app.. but as the app grows and gets more complex, little things like this would add up right?

Comment: @Frode - will look into that, but you think that will make a difference as far as efficiency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will probably be accused of heresy but I wouldn't mind using jQuery (or similar) *if there is good reason for it*. Some thoughts:

1. If highlighting is just a transient effect (in the sense of `$.effect("highlight")` - [ref](http://api.jqueryui.com/highlight-effect/) - *THIS IS NOT THE CASE HERE*), I believe jQuery would be a good option for optimization.
2. If you really mind the watches (you should in general, when models start getting bigger), why not implementing this functionality in a directive applied to the root of the list. Some pseudo-code to explain:

   ```
   <tbody highlighter="some.expression.here">
       <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
           <td id="{{item.id}}">item.id</td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
   ```

   So, the `highlighter` directive knows somehow to highlight a row by applying a single watch, e.g (again very rough almost-pseudo-code):

   ```
   // in the link(scope,elem) function:
   scope.$watch("highlightedRowId", function(newval, oldval) {
       elem.find("#" + oldval).removeClass("highlighted");
       elem.find("#" + newval).addClass("highlighted");
   });
   ```
3. (as haki comments) Does the model really need to get this big? Are there any ways to avoid it? Is the trade-off "Use jQuery and less watches" **vs.** "Clean code and more watches" worth it?

These are just some very rough thoughts on an interesting and open ended question... Actually I started writing a comment, but it became too long soon. Have fun anyway!

Comment: excellent! i like your directive idea... will try it out and report back on speed differences.